# Unable to Set SVG As BackGround

Tags: html, css, svg, background

I have and html page And there i want to change background jpg image to svg,

```
<section class="hero-section set-bg" style="background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns%23' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='svg37' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 200 200' height='800' width='800'%3E%3Cmetadata id='metadata41'%3E%3Crdf:RDF%3E%3Ccc:Work rdf:about=''%3E%3Cdc:format%3Eimage/svg+xml%3C/dc:format%3E%3Cdc:type rdf:resource='http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage' /%3E%3C/cc:Work%3E%3C/rdf:RDF%3E%3C/metadata%3E%3Crect id='rect2' height='200' width='200' fill='%23006aff' /%3E%3Cdefs id='defs29'%3E%3ClinearGradient y2='0' x2='0' y1='88' x1='88' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='a'%3E%3Cstop id='stop4' stop-color='%238f8f8f' offset='0' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop6' stop-color='%23e3e3e3' offset='1' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient y2='160' x2='168' y1='76' x1='75' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='b'%3E%3Cstop id='stop9' stop-color='%238f8f8f' offset='0' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop11' stop-color='%23b3b3b3' offset='0.09' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop13' stop-color='%23c9c9c9' offset='0.18' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop15' stop-color='%23dbdbdb' offset='0.31' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop17' stop-color='%23e8e8e8' offset='0.44' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop19' stop-color='%23f2f2f2' offset='0.59' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop21' stop-color='%23fafafa' offset='0.75' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop23' stop-color='%23FFFFFF' offset='1' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cfilter height='200%25' width='200%25' y='0' x='0' id='c'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur id='feGaussianBlur26' stdDeviation='12' in='SourceGraphic' /%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpolygon id='polygon31' points='0 174 0 0 174 0' fill='url(%23a)' /%3E%3Cpath id='path33' d='M121.8 174C59.2 153.1 0 174 0 174s63.5-73.8 87-94c24.4-20.9 87-80 87-80S107.9 104.4 121.8 174z' filter='url(%23c)' fill-opacity='.5' fill='%23000' /%3E%3Cpath id='path35' d='M142.7 142.7C59.2 142.7 0 174 0 174s42-66.3 74.9-99.3S174 0 174 0S142.7 62.6 142.7 142.7z' fill='url(%23b)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");" >

</section>
```

When i do like this from code it does not work and code transfer to

```
background-image: url(undefined)
```

setting background with and image works fine and also settiong svg background for browser is also work but when i use it in code it does not.

i also tried removing class set-bg

i think there is quotes issue maybe

Comment: if any one need code visit https://booksmotion.com  and there is a hero-background image and i want to transfer that to svg (please Don't Down vote I am Not Promoting My Website )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner quotation marks should be " and the section needs a size.

```css
html, body, section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-section set-bg" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns%23' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='svg37' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 200 200' height='800' width='800'%3E%3Cmetadata id='metadata41'%3E%3Crdf:RDF%3E%3Ccc:Work rdf:about=''%3E%3Cdc:format%3Eimage/svg+xml%3C/dc:format%3E%3Cdc:type rdf:resource='http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage' /%3E%3C/cc:Work%3E%3C/rdf:RDF%3E%3C/metadata%3E%3Crect id='rect2' height='200' width='200' fill='%23006aff' /%3E%3Cdefs id='defs29'%3E%3ClinearGradient y2='0' x2='0' y1='88' x1='88' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='a'%3E%3Cstop id='stop4' stop-color='%238f8f8f' offset='0' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop6' stop-color='%23e3e3e3' offset='1' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient y2='160' x2='168' y1='76' x1='75' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='b'%3E%3Cstop id='stop9' stop-color='%238f8f8f' offset='0' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop11' stop-color='%23b3b3b3' offset='0.09' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop13' stop-color='%23c9c9c9' offset='0.18' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop15' stop-color='%23dbdbdb' offset='0.31' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop17' stop-color='%23e8e8e8' offset='0.44' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop19' stop-color='%23f2f2f2' offset='0.59' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop21' stop-color='%23fafafa' offset='0.75' /%3E%3Cstop id='stop23' stop-color='%23FFFFFF' offset='1' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cfilter height='200%25' width='200%25' y='0' x='0' id='c'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur id='feGaussianBlur26' stdDeviation='12' in='SourceGraphic' /%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpolygon id='polygon31' points='0 174 0 0 174 0' fill='url(%23a)' /%3E%3Cpath id='path33' d='M121.8 174C59.2 153.1 0 174 0 174s63.5-73.8 87-94c24.4-20.9 87-80 87-80S107.9 104.4 121.8 174z' filter='url(%23c)' fill-opacity='.5' fill='%23000' /%3E%3Cpath id='path35' d='M142.7 142.7C59.2 142.7 0 174 0 174s42-66.3 74.9-99.3S174 0 174 0S142.7 62.6 142.7 142.7z' fill='url(%23b)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A&quot;);” >

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that by following:-

```css
body {
  background: #f06d06;
  padding: 20px;
}

section {
  background: white;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/NATO_Map_Symbol_-_Friendly_Unit_-_Solid.svg) bottom center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
</section>
```